# Linear algebra and unknown sum limits

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, summation

I have been struggling with the this one.

Let's assume that:

1. $N$ is a large integer
2. $\epsilon$ is real and $0<\epsilon<1$
3. $\rho$ is real, $0<\rho<1$ and $\rho N$ is an integer
4. $\alpha_i$ are $\rho N$ real and positive numbers, sorted in a descending order and $\alpha_i \ge 1$ for all $i$
5. $P_i$ are $\rho N$ real and positive numbers, sorted in a descending order

They satisfy the following relations:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{\rho N} \alpha_i = N \\
&\sum_{i=1}^{\rho N} \alpha_i \rho P_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\rho N} P_i\,.
\end{align}

We also assume that there is an index $1 \le I_{\epsilon} < \rho N$, so that

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{I_{\epsilon}} \alpha_i = \epsilon N\,,
\end{align}
yet $I_{\epsilon}$ is unknown.

What can we say about the properties of $\alpha_i$ in order to satisfy the following condition:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{I_\epsilon} \alpha_i \rho P_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\epsilon\rho N} P_i
\end{align}

It obviously works if $\alpha_i$ are identical. Assuming they aren't, what general properties should $\alpha_i$ have so that the last condition is met?

Thanks